# Why unsupported operand type for ** in python classes?

Tags: python-3.x, class, methods

I was trying my hand in coding on a site. The task was to create 2 classes - rectangle and circle. with instance variables l, b and r respectively. The classes also needed to have a method to area which would return area. So I wrote the code, tested it on spyder. Worked correctly with all test cases. But giving following error in the site's IDE:

```
 File "Solution.py", line 21, in area
    return math.pi*(r**2)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'Circle' and 'int'
```

below is my code:

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self,l,b):
        self.l = l
        self.b = b
    def area(l,b):
        return l*b

class Circle:
    def __init__(self,r):
        self.r = r
    def area(r):
        return math.pi*(r**2)
```

PS. I had imported math module. Unable to figure out the cause of this error. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

you are missing the `self` variable in the Circle function (which passes as `'r'`), 
the code should look like the following (i changed it a bit in a way which would make sense to me, but i hope you get what the bug was):

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self,l,b):
        self.l = l
        self.b = b
    def area(self):
        return self.l*self.b

class Circle:
    def __init__(self,r):
        self.r = r
    def area(self):
        return math.pi*(self.r**2)
```

or you can use some static implementation of that function instead.